# COunt Colored Cells with Text Match in another column

Tags: excel

I want to count colored cells in one column based on text match from another column, in excel. For example, for each employee in column 1, I want to count the no. of highlighted cells against his name in another column.

Comment: As far as I know, this can't be done directly. Excel cannot have a formatting condition as an *input* to a formula, but Excel can have a formatting condition as an *output* of a formula (via conditional formatting). So the only way you could accomplish what you are asking is if you use a formula to conditionally format a certain range of cells, and then use that same conditional formatting formula to count the amount of cells formatted as a part of your desired formula.

Comment: I tried using the color count through VBA code. But I'm unable to count the no. of colored cells for each employee..

Comment: I was unaware that you were using VBA. I recommend explicitly stating that in the question and also adding the VBA tag. Per my previous comment, it can be done without VBA, but you would have to also use conditional formatting.